# Belgium clones leffe brune

Tags: beer, belgian, clone-recipe

has anyone made a Leffe Brune clone, please tell me what you used and how it turned out?

Comment: Seems hard to find a clone recipe. But why not brew a dubbel and see how one can adjust that?

Comment: Are you looking for an extract or all-grain recipe?

Answer (score 1):

Since "Leffe Brune" is one of my favorite beer.
 I have tried to clone it for a while.
 I have now created a recipe that is incredibly similar.
 I can not distinguish between the beer in a test.
 Smoked malt gives the taste of pine tar, and that use of
 Safbrew T-58 provides a high FG, allowing that the sweetness remains.
 All malts are from Weyermann.

Reciepe
http://www.brewersfriend.com/homebrew/recipe/view/258683/porterline-syndrome-leffe-brune-

Comment: Hi user12586. While external links are not disallowed, we do like answers to be primarily "contained" on the site. Can you add the recipe itself to your answer?

Answer (score -2):

brewtoad is a great place to search for clones. https://www.brewtoad.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Leffe+Brune+Clone